# How can I resolve the problem 20/3 is 6.666 and 6.667?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to create a program where the person resolves Fraction to decimal problems.

I'm having problems like 20/3 and I think it would be correct that the boy writes 6.666 or 6.667.

I was designing this formula:

```
ABS(RC - R) < 0.001
```

I mean RC is computer result and R boy's result. And compares if the result is correct.

I give to the user a fraction problem, and it contains the solution (always until three decimals), how can I do to not obligate the user to write exactly the answer?

By the way, sorry if this is not the category. Please, help to edit the category.

OK, I'm obligatting the user type 3 digits.. so, I was thinking if there's a way to accept two digits. I guess that's not possible, but for that reason, I want to comment this situation

Comment: Ok.  And what is the problem?

Comment: Are you always expecting accuracy to three decimal places?  For example, do you want to accept both 6.66 and 6.67, as well?

Comment: Your solution is the generally accepted solution to this problem.

Comment: Except to the boy that enters 18.  Or 21.  Or wtf?  Extra credit for "lol"?  You'll have to indicate whether you accept banker's rounding.

Comment: Can you clarify more specifically what you're trying to do?

Comment: OK, I just wanted to know if this would be the right formula to know if the user's answer is correct.. Although I've got another question.. I'm obligatting the user typing 3 digits (because my absolute error is 0.001).. there's no a possible way to write two digits? I mean, (0.16 | 0.17) (0.166 | 0.167)

Because the answers inside the parentesis are correct, I guess if there another solution to solve this

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is

```
if (ABS(RC - R) <= 0.001)
{
    //the answer is close enough
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the issue.  The result of 20/3 is 6.6666 recurring, in this application the correct answer will be either 6.666 or 6.667, but **not** 6.665 or 6.668.

Here is a solution, assuming you always want precision to be down to 3 decimal places.

```
decimal RC = 20/3;
decimal R = 6.666;
int numDecimals = 3; //edit this to change precision

public bool IsAnswerCorrect(decimal R, decimal RC, int numDecimals) {
    int precision = Math.Pow(10, numDecimals);
    RC *= precision; 
    R *= precision; 

    return R == Math.Floor(RC) || R == Math.Ceiling(RC);
}
```

using ABS(RC - R) <= 0.001 would mean the application would determine anything between 6.6656 and 6.6676 as correct.

Comment: Yes, It looks like the idea I posted.. I like it.. one question, there's no possible to obligate the user write until three digits, right? It's only a question

Comment: I'm not completely understanding what you mean, but I think you mean restricting the user to only enter 3 digits? Sure, you can, but that is front end work and not really related to this question.  However, using this method would mean you can choose what precision you want by changing the precision value. (I'm editing my answer now to demonstrate what I mean)

Comment: if you change `int precision = 1000;` to `int numDecimals = 3; int precision = Math.Pow(10, numDecimals);` it might be a little bit easier to understand. At least I think it's more obvious to change numDecimals to four instead of writing precision = 10000.

Comment: Thanks Bakapii, i've changed my answer to reflect your suggestion =)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Jace looks good, but I wouldn't trust it without testing it (because this is a little bit tricky).

I would start by writing some unit tests, to define exactly what behaviour you expect, something like this:

```
void CloseButIncorrectAnswer_ShouldFail()
{
    double computerResult = 20/3;
    double resultToCheck = 6.665;

    Assert.IsFalse (IsAnswerCorrect(computerResult, resultToCheck));
}

void AnswerMatchesToThreeDP_ShouldBeAccepted()
{
    double computerResult = 20/3;
    double resultToCheck = 6.666;

    Assert.IsTrue (IsAnswerCorrect(computerResult, resultToCheck));
}

void CloseWithCorrectRoundingAnswer_ShouldBeAccepted()
{
    double computerResult = 20/3;
    double resultToCheck = 6.667;

    Assert.IsTrue (IsAnswerCorrect(computerResult, resultToCheck));
}
```